# Enter individual numbers into iPhone contacts

Tags: iphone, contacts

I have a list of phone numbers:

Joe Blow (123) 456-7890
Steph Smith (234) 345-5678
Iggy Ziggy (876) 756-7550

Is there a way to import these individual numbers into iPhone contacts without typing them in by hand?
(or receiving a call/message from them)

Comment: I have not received a call or message, so new.

Comment: If they don’t call you or you them, where would they come from in the first place?

Comment: Do you already have this data compiled, and if so, in what form?

Comment: At stated, I have a list of numbers. I am asking if there is some sort of import functionality. Perhaps the list is in a text file. Then somewhere I select "import to Contacts" and the numbers will then appear in Contacts.

Comment: No Mac ........

Comment: Can you be more specific about the format the list is in currently?

Comment: its just text. It could made to be whatever works, e.g. csv.

Answer (score 1):

If you put them into a vCard (.vcf) file and if your iPhone is synced to iCloud, you can import them via the settings in Contacts on iCloud.com as you can see below:

[image]

There are also 3rd party service options such as Google Contacts as you can read from [this article](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/import-contacts-iphone-csv-57097.html) with specific directions if you want to import them from a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

#### iCloud Import Contacts

If you sync your contacts with iCloud, you can import contacts using the VCard format.  This must be done using the Contacts app on iCloud.com

[image]

#### Outlook.com Import Contacts

Other options are the online email clients like Outlook.com, GMail, Yahoo, etc.  For example, using Outlook.com, you can import a CSV file of your contacts as shown below.  You can access the function by clicking on "Manage Contacts" or the icon that looks like "a person with a gear" in the upper right hand corner of the web app.

[image: Outlook.com Import Contacts]

#### Desktop Options and Manual Entry

Getting your contacts into [vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) (for iCloud) may be more difficult than just inputting them manually.  There are are some Excel plugins that allow you to batch convert CSV/Excel to vCard.  I’d avoid the “free online converters” because you’re basically filling their databases with known good email addresses that will get most likely get spammed.

If you have access to the desktop clients, you can import into those apps and then sync with the cloud versions (I have this scenario set up personally)

- The Desktop versions of Outlook (Mac & PC) allow you to [import contacts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-contacts-to-Outlook-bb796340-b58a-46c1-90c7-b549b8f3c5f8) and sync to your Contacts.
- Desktop version of Contacts allows for importing of vCard (.vcf), Archive files (.abbu)and CSV.  See Apple Support Document: [Import contacts from other apps into Contacts for Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/contacts/import-contacts-from-other-apps-adrbk1457/mac)

#### TL;DR

The App versions of Contacts don't allow you to import, however, the desktop version of email clients (i.e. Outlook) and online services (i.e. Outlook.com, Gmail, etc) as well as Apple's own Mac version of Contacts allows you to import from various formats.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. More detail would be needed to see if this is an acceptable answer.

Comment: One can also import contact data from a .cvs file using the Contacts app in macOS. Data can be mapped to the standard contact card fields. iCloud sync in macOS and iOS will make those contacts available on the iPhone. See also: https://www.easeus.com/iphone-data-transfer/transfer-contacts-from-mac-to-iphone-without-itunes.html

Comment: I’m a little slow today since I’m posting from my iPad.  But there are options, I just can’t test out the desktop options at the moment

Comment: I am trying using Outlook as one of your suggestions. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-contacts-to-outlook-bb796340-b58a-46c1-90c7-b549b8f3c5f8 When I get to step 9, instead of a Finish button, I see a Next button but it is disabled. so I am stuck. No matter the destination, I can't get past this.

Comment: Without seeing your data,  I'm guessing that you might have to go in a manually map your custom fields to define what data goes where.  If that button is greyed out, there's an issue with your data.